# VMWare Converter P2V into VirtualBox getting VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-converter

When using VirtualBox 5.0.4 on Ubuntu Server 14.04, I get VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED when trying to import a VMDK which was created using VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone Client v6.0.0, as a P2V from a local machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation.

Having read what Google/SO say, it seems I'm faced with a different scenario as I've tried many options.

I believe it's due to the new version of VMWare Converter perhaps generating a new type of VMDK that VirtualBox doesn't recognize. I tried the P2V with support for VMWare WorkStation 11.x and 10.x and both gave the same error.

Any advice? tia.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the VMDK image file to VDI using QEMU tools:

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O vdi image.vmdk image.vdi
```

And use the converted VDI image.

Comment: sounds about right. it's no longer something i am working on but converting in another instance worked well.